# SIGABRT error on getline code

Tags: c++, xcode, getline

I'm retrieving data from a std::ifstream using the getline function and am getting a SIGABRT error from Xcode when it reaches the end of file. I realize in its current implementation putting in this function seems redundant but I am adding more line processing after I have it working. Here is the code, the function is continuously being called in a while loop.

```
bool setRead(std::string& read, std::ifstream& inStream) {
    std::string data = "";
    if (std::getline(inStream, data)) {
        read = data;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I thought that when getline reached the eof that the if statement would evaluate to false and then my function would return false. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why not simply `if (std::getline(inStream, read))` BTW?

Comment: std::getline does not return a boolean.

Comment: @Nighthawk441 Yes/No: Essentially it boils down to [`inStream.good()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I forgot about it's new C++11 extensions

Comment: @Nighthawk441 No, that's no [tag:c++11] extension. It ever worked so ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ My mistake, I read the docs operator bool() but did not notice it had void* as well.